# flutter statusbar color not same with Appbar Color

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I have set the statusbar color to transparent. But still not the same with Appbar.

```
// on main method
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    SystemUiOverlayStyle systemUiOverlayStyle =
        SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.transparent);
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(systemUiOverlayStyle);
  }

// on a widget build method
Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          appBar: AppBar(
            brightness: Brightness.light,
            centerTitle: true,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            elevation: 0,
            title: Text('发现', style: BMTextStyle.black_56),
            
          ),
          body: SafeArea(
            top: false,
            child: TabBarView(controller: _controller, children: <Widget>[
              _buildPageContentAccordingIndex(0),
              _buildPageContentAccordingIndex(1),
            ]),
          ),
        ),
```

The result is the statusbar color seems gray, and the Scaffold is white. So how to make them the same? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `AnnotatedRegion` inside each `Stateful Widget` (basically every screen) you make adjustments to regarding the status bar. I previously did it some other way, but AnnotatedRegion makes sure the status bar updates its style again when you use Navigator.pop(context) to come back to this screen. Just wrap the Scaffold around with `AnnotatedRegion` and set the value to your `systemUiOverlayStyle`  variable like so:

```dart
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemUiOverlayStyle _statusBarStyle = SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
      statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
    );

    return AnnotatedRegion(
      value: _statusBarStyle,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          brightness: Brightness.light,
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          elevation: 0,
          title: Text('发现', style: BMTextStyle.black_56),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          top: false,
          child: TabBarView(controller: _controller, children: <Widget>[
            _buildPageContentAccordingIndex(0),
            _buildPageContentAccordingIndex(1),
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: Finally fix it. My widgets are builded using PageView without appbar, So in the safeare use the 'top: false' to resolve the problem. Thank you.